# Cannot open file downloaded from Azure Storage account

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Why is it when downloaded I am not able to open a file which was uploaded to my Azure storage account as a block blob?

Initially I thought it was because of the way I uploaded it. But manually uploaded files when downloaded wont open as well.
This is the message I see when I try to open the downloaded file-
[image]

Type of file - .jpg
Here are the properties of the file on Azure -

[image]

My graphql api calls the function below which is written in python -

```
@mutation.field("fileUpload")
def resolve_fileUpload(_, info, file):
    print(file['containerName'])
    file_path = file['file'] if 'file' in file else None
    file_name = file['fileName'] if 'fileName' in file else None
    file_type = file['fileType'] if 'fileType' in file else None
    file_extension = file['fileExtension'] if 'fileExtension' in file else None
    uploaded_date = file['uploadedDate'] if 'uploadedDate' in file else None
    container_name = file['containerName'] if 'containerName' in file else None

    try:
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(
            container_name)
        if not container_client.exists():
            container_client.create_container()
            container_client.set_container_metadata(
                metadata={'Created_Date': uploaded_date})

        with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
            content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='image/jpeg')
            metadata = {'File_Name': file_name, 'Uploaded_Date': uploaded_date, 'Container_Name': container_name,
                        'File_Type': file_type, 'File_Extension': file_extension}
            result = container_client.upload_blob(
                name=file_name, data=file_path, metadata=metadata, content_settings=content_settings)

            # result = container_client.upload_blob(
            #     name=file_name, data=file_path)

    except AzureException as e:
        if e.status_code == 200:
            return {
                "status": e.status_code,
                "error": "",
                "fileUrl": result.url
            }
        else:
            return {
                "status": e.status_code,
                "error": e.message,
                "fileUrl": result.url
            }
    else:
        return {
            "status": 200,
            "error": "",
            "fileUrl": result.url
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details like what kind of file it is, code for uploading the file, blob properties etc.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with your upload code. Reason I say this is because the size of the blob is 44bytes which doesn't seem right. Have you tried uploading the file using Azure Portal and downloading it?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes I have tried that as well. I am still not able to open it.

Comment: Hmmm…that’s weird. Were you able to open the source file properly on your local machine?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes it opens fine on my local machine.

Comment: Can you share that file? Let me try it with my storage account.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am not sure on how to attach the file here.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the original image file there just like other images you added to your question .

Comment: @GauravMantri Its added

Comment: Thanks. I tried to upload the file you shared and I was able to successfully download it. I uploaded through portal and downloaded from there only.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: what is the code you used to download the file?